# Caminho entre nodos de uma arvore binaria de busca

Tags: algoritmo, estrutura-de-dados, árvore-binária

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso criar um algoritmo que ira definir se um caminho entre o valor a e b são validos, minha dúvida é em relação a essa regras, por exemplo entre o nodo 3 e o 7 exite um caminho valido, mas entre os nodos 3 e o 10 eu iria precisar realizar uma volta, isso ainda o torna valido?! e entre os nodos 1 e 7 também existem um caminho valido?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provavelmente é um exercício, certo? É complicado dizer se algo é válido sem o contexto e as regras que podem ser aplicadas nesse caso.

A primeira pergunta que você deve fazer é se essa árvore suporta navegação de um elemento "filho" (descendente) para o seu "pai" (ascendente). Algumas estruturas de dados armazenam apenas os descendentes e não haveria um caminho viável entre `3` e `10`.

No entanto, se a busca começa pela raiz da árvore, você pode percorrer a árvore duas vezes, uma buscando o `3` e outra buscando `10`. O caminho será a combinação dos dois caminhos a partir da raiz.

Enfim, é por isso que eu detesto exercícios abstratos de faculdade.

Comment: Olá @utluiz, pois é em minha estrutura hoje o "filho" não sabe que é seu "pai", reavaliado a questão com seus pontos de vista acabei percebendo que o objetivo do exercício é ser simples mesmo. No caso os exemplos citados acima só existiriam os caminhos 3-7, ou seja não existe ( não ao menos nessa proposta ) aquela volta para o nodo pai.